# Why do I have two kernel on my boot manager?

Tags: fedora, kernel, upgrade

After my PC runs I can see three options which are
`Fedora (5.3.16-300. fc31.x86_64) 31
Fedora (5.3.7-301. fc31.x86_64) 31
Fedora (0-rescu-bd .....) 31
Windows 7`
Searching on the Net, I found that **"kernel-5.3.16-300.fc31.x86_64.rpm"** is a kernel and also **"kernel-5.3.7-301.fc31"** is a kernel too.
**My questions are:**
Do I have two kernel on my system at the same time?
What is the advantage of two extra options? (By extra I mean the other options, for example the second and third options.) **Many thanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I have two kernel on my system at the same time?

Yes.

> What is the advantage of two extra options? (By extra I mean the other
>   options, for example the second and third options.)

If the `kernel-5.3.16-300` proved to be bad, and broke your system, you could still boot from the earlier `kernel-5.3.7-301`.

Rescue kernel is for exactly what it suggests, rescuing your system.

> "Rescue mode provides the ability to boot a small Fedora environment
>   entirely from CD-ROM, or some other boot method, instead of the
>   system's hard drive. As the name implies, rescue mode is provided to
>   rescue you from something. During normal operation, your Fedora system
>   uses files located on your system's hard drive to do everything — run
>   programs, store your files, and more. However, there may be times when
>   you are unable to get Fedora running completely enough to access files
>   on your system's hard drive. Using rescue mode, you can access the
>   files stored on your system's hard drive, even if you cannot actually
>   run Fedora from that hard drive."

Answer (score 1):

It is another way to ensure the system will start up just fine. If a kernel suddenly spits out errors and doesn't work well, having a back-up plan is great for keeping a smooth operating system. Otherwise, you'd be tasked with figuring it out.

At least, this is one reason I know of distributions doing that.